# How to remove an item from a redis geohash?

Tags: hash, redis, geo, redis-3.2

Redis 3.2 feature the geohash type.

[`GEOADD` is used to add keys:](http://redis.io/commands/geoadd)

```
> GEOADD restaurants 32.0 34.0 Falafel
(integer) 1
> GEOADD restaurants 32.1 34.1 Pizza
(integer) 1
```

`GEORADIUS` is used to make a geo query:

```
> GEORADIUS restaurants 32.05 34.05 100 km WITHDIST
1) 1) "Falafel"
   2) "7.2230"
2) 1) "Pizza"
   2) "7.2213"
```

However, `HDEL` does not seem to work:

```
> HDEL restaurants Falafel
(error) WRONGTYPE Operation against a key holding the wrong kind of value
```

**How do I delete, or set a TTL, to a key within a geo hash?**

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Geohashes are sorted sets, so the [right command is `ZREM`](http://redis.io/commands/zrem):

```
> ZREM restaurants Falafel
(integer) 1

> GEORADIUS restaurants 32.05 34.05 100 km WITHDIST
1) 1) "Pizza"
   2) "7.2213"
```

Comment: Am I missing anything? It's merely naming: [Actually, there isn’t any new data structure under the hood: a GeoSet is simply a Redis SortedSet](http://cristian.regolo.cc/2015/07/07/introducing-the-geo-api-in-redis.html)

Comment: Nope, you're not missing. Your forgot to answer your question about TTL though (no TTL for members in the structure)

Comment: How do you remove all?

Comment: Wait what, how strange is that, you can remove using a value? Does it mean it will remove all `Falafel` independently of their coordinates? Redis looks weird …

Comment: Oh I tried it, it turns out you can only have one `Falafel` it's even stranger than I though. I wonder how this can be used in practice.